# ScreenFlow when launched from QuickAction, is finished. And when we hit the browser back button the flow is relaunched/Re-executing the flow

Tags: quickaction, screen-flow

The Screen flow is launched from quick actions on the contact record page. The flow is re-executing/ launched every time when the browser back button is clicked or trying to go back.

So the conditions/ decisions added will be executed again. Example :- on the verbal Commitment Status check decision for checkconditionvalidation and goes through the next decision and exits. works flawlessly, no issue works as designed/ excepted. But when the browser navigation buttons is clicked then the flow is running. For some of the Screen elements i have added an LWC toast message.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it makes no difference, but I wonder why people are using that button. Having said that, you're right that the flow shouldn't auto-run when the back button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, makes no difference. Any ideas or anyway to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2):

I have a hunch that when you click the screen flow button, it puts something into the URL or page parameters behind the scenes. I'd add an element at the end of the flow to navigate to the record, explicitly navigating to a "clean" URL.

Comment: Yes you are right about that. And i did exactly same thing, which worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark it as the best answer so others can learn from it in the future.