# Back button keeps re-executing my flow

Tags: button, url, screen-flow, action

I'm trying to prevent re-executing a flow when the back button is clicked in the browser after starting a flow via quick action. I've seen this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414701/screenflow-when-launched-from-quickaction-is-finished-and-when-we-hit-the-brow) [ScreenFlow when launched from QuickAction, is finished. And when we hit the browser back button the flow is relaunched/Re-executing the flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414701/screenflow-when-launched-from-quickaction-is-finished-and-when-we-hit-the-brow) with the same issue and the issue seemed to be resolved there. Hoever they have not addressed the actual answer on how to redirect the flow to an empty URL.

I've tried adding the 'navigate everywhere' component with a record navigation and a URL navigation with the original record Id, but that does not solve my problem. see link for screenshots of the process and issue. I've added an image of my flow too. Tried the same for URL with /{!recordId}

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Presumably this screen flow is on a lightning record page? I've solved this issue by having the screen flow start with a "welcome" or "preamble" screen that simply has a Display Text element. User has to click Next to get anything to happen. Hence, back button is benign